# Can I recall my US Senator or Representatives in Congress in the state of Utah?

Tags: united-states, congress

I live in Utah,

- **Is there an proceedure to recall a senator or representatives in Congress in my state?**
- **What are the steps in executing that procedure?**

Comment: Guess you need your own Hatch Act :)

Comment: Agree with the duplicate vote. The answer is defined by the U.S. Constitution, so state is irrelevant and the answer is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Not currently.  Impeachment is the only route.  Plans to implement recall legislation have been discussed recently. http://m.sltrib.com/sltrib/mobile3/56482734-219/allow-allowing-counties-elections.html.csp

Comment: Note that those plans only related to state offices, not U.S. Senators or Representatives. An amendment to the U.S. Constitution would be required to allow recall of a member of Congress from any state. States may provide in their own constitutions for the recall of their state legislatures (or other state/local officials,) but the U.S. Constitution does not allow it for members of Congress.